# Rename [XBMC] tag to [Kodi]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tags, tag-synonym-request

XBMC was renamed/rebranded to Kodi: http://kodi.tv/introducing-kodi-14/

I'm not too clear on the right way to propose this.

Proposing:

- new Kodi tag
- make tag synonym for XBMC to point/resolve to Kodi
- maybe migrate all xbmc tags to kodi + synonym pointer?

Current situation results in things like this:

[Kodi not updating video tags correctly](https://superuser.com/questions/896960/kodi-not-updating-video-tags-correctly)

^ Title reflects new name yet tag does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Proposing:
>
> - new Kodi tag
> - make tag synonym for XBMC to point/resolve to Kodi
> - maybe migrate all xbmc tags to kodi + synonym pointer?

All these are done. [xbmc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/xbmc) wiki was pretty good, I've done minor dress up to reflect the new name. Tag wiki might need further edits